# Need help conditionally formatting table column

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

I am an Electronics Engineer with some programming background (mostly self-taught). I created a Flask project with some code pulling SQL data and passing it to a Jinja2 HTML template (via Pandas dataframe.to_html). I also have a CSS template with some styling. My final goal is to display this data in a table on an HTML page. There is one column I would like to color conditionally utilizing the data in the columns cell. I would also like to be able to select each column which will then open another page with corresponding data.

[image: Example of what I wanted (Created in Excel)]

I have gone through many iterations of this utilizing many different thought processes. I applied some formatting within pandas first which I found was limited and to difficult to pass the (styler object) into the HTML template for further formatting. I have tried to figure out how to format it with HTML and with CSS but cannot seems to quite figure it out.

I am not married to the HTML out. If it is easier to achieve with a GUI like Tkinter, or PyQT I will go that route. I just really would like to know the "Most correct way" to proceed to accomplish this.

HTML Template

```
{% block content1 %}
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
<table class="mystyle">
{{ table | safe}}
</table>
{% endblock content1 %}
```

Python Code

```
@app.route("/table", methods=('POST', 'GET'))
def table():
    return render_template(
        'table.html', table=current_state.to_html(classes = 'mystyle'), title="Table", )
```

CSS Code

```
.mystyle 
{
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.mystyle td 
{
font-size:12pt
}

.mystyle td, th 
{
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding:2px;
    color: black;
}
```

Thank You!!

Comment: You could import bootstrap or other css libraries to make more functionality in html tables

Comment: I did mess around with bootstrap as well but could not figure out how to use it to conditionally format just one column of information. It seems that I may be bound to learn jQuery. I think that I could use it for the formatting as well as the selecting of the row for more info.

Comment: What you're looking for is called css selectors or css classes. For example, add a class to the third column. Then you can make a selector for it

Comment: Oh, ok...I appreciate the insight. Off to accomplish some reading. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not the most elegant way but this is how I solved my issue. I used JQuery, targeted the third column with (td:nth-child(3)), and then used an if statement to test the value of the cell. I then utilized an inline CSS command to format the text color accordingly. I am going to make it better when I get a chance using a switch/case statement but at least for now it works.

Thanks for all the help!

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CMMS_Table tr:first").prepend("<th>More Info</th>");
            $("#CMMS_Table tr:gt(0)").prepend("<td><button> INFO </button></td>");
            $('#CMMS_Table th:nth-child(3), table td:nth-child(3)').addClass('state');
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'WE') $(this).css('color', '#FF9900'); });
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'UMaint') $(this).css('color', '#FF0000'); });
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'SMaint') $(this).css('color', '#FA8072'); });
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'WP') $(this).css('color', '#CCCC33'); });
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'EquipInstall') $(this).css('color', '#0066FF'); });
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'UPartWt') $(this).css('color', '#990099'); });
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'LE') $(this).css('color', '#CC6600'); });
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'ProdRun') $(this).css('color', '#00FF00'); });
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'MatlAssist') $(this).css('color', '#CC9999'); });
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'OQual') $(this).css('color', '#C993FF'); });
            $('#CMMS_Table td:nth-child(3)').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'EquipEng') $(this).css('color', '#B22222'); });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="top_img">
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='double_logo_crop.jpg' )}}" />
        </div>
        {{ table|safe }}
    </div>
    <br>
</body>
</div> -->

</html>
```